# I need help creating a directory that gives me the exact date like example /2019/09/03/?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

Code looks something like this, Please let me know on changes :

```
import os

import datetime

path = "/home/xxx/"

current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')

command = "mkdir {0}".format(current_time)

os.chdir(path)

os.system(command)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this question is for nested directory e.g. 2019/09/03:

```
import os
import datetime

path = "<define_path>"
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S')
os.chdir(path)
os.makedirs(current_time)
```